# How to use theme framework in ambari 2.1 for customized service?

Tags: ambari

How to use theme framework with ambari to provide theme like combo,slider to the property? I need to add a toggle with yes or no property for licence.
I am following the below link but not  able to see themes for the customize service.
http://search-hadoop.com/m/g7Bc62I7Ncfx9tB1&subj=Re+Using+theme+framework+on+my+own+stack

Steps which i have done:

1. Added theme.json entry in metainfo.xml
2. Created theme.json as:

{
"name": "default",

"description": "Default theme for HBASE service",

"configuration": {

```
"layouts": [

  {

   "name": "default",

    "tabs": [

    {

     "name": "settings",

        "display-name": "Settings",

        "layout": {

          "tab-columns": "3",

          "tab-rows": "3",

          "sections": [

            {

              "name": "section-memory",

              "display-name": "Server",

              "row-index": "0",

              "column-index": "0",

              "row-span": "1",

              "column-span": "2",

              "section-columns": "2",

              "section-rows": "1",

              "subsections": [

                {

                  "name": "subsection-col1",

                  "row-index": "0",

                  "column-index": "0",

                  "row-span": "1",

                  "column-span": "1"

                },

                {
                  "name": "subsection-col2",

                  "row-index": "0",

                  "column-index": "1",

                  "row-span": "1",

                  "column-span": "1"

                }

              ]

            }
            ]
            }
            }
            ]
            }
            ],
         "placement": {
  "configuration-layout": "default",
  "configs": [
    {
      "config": "genera/licence",
      "subsection-name": "subsection-col1"
    }
]
},
"widgets": [
  {
    "config": "genera/licence",
    "widget": {
      "type": "toggle"
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

3. In general.xml present in configuration folder as:
   Added following entry:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prXfx.png)

But still it is not reflecting it.

Comment: Above steps work fine. Mistake was wrong spelling of general in theme.json file. After correcting, it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Above steps work fine. Mistake was wrong spelling of general in theme.json file. After correcting, it worked correctly.